# What are the differences between "You gave up", "You gave it up" and "You gave up on that"?

Tags: phrase-usage

What are the differences between "And then you gave up", "And then you gave it up", "And then you gave up on that?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Cambridge Dictionary:

[Give up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-up): "to stop trying to do something before you have finished, usually because it is too difficult"

[Give [something] up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-sth-up): "to stop doing a regular activity or job"

[Give up on [something]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-up-on-sb-sth): "to expect someone or something to fail"

Comment: "Give it up" *can* be a case of "give [something] up" if there's a clear antecedent for "it", but otherwise Jasper's answer is better for the "it" case.

Comment: Yeah, it's why I upvoted him. Though, with that said, neither of the meanings he listed are listed in that dictionary entry, and the meanings I listed are the three most closely related ones that illustrate the difference between them.

Comment: Meanings that aren't listed in the dictionary entry are probably the most important to get across to language learners.

Comment: @R. -- This answer covers more phrases that the original poster asked about than my answer does, and cites a suitable dictionary.  It probably provides a definition for a larger fraction of uses of "give it up" than my answer does.  I upvoted it.

Comment: @Jasper: Yes, both are good, and I didn't have anything against (much less downvote) this one.

Comment: @R.. '...if there's a clear antecedent for "it"' - Did you mean to say 'antecedent for "it"", instead? Otherwise, unless I misunderstand something, the antecedent for "it"  is the word "give". Not?

Comment: @brilliant: The sense in which I'm using antecedent is the grammatical one: antecedent of a pronoun, the prior noun to which it refers. For example, in "He really loved smoking, but decided to give it up", it's clear that "it" refers to "smoking" and the sense of "give it up" is the "give [something] up" in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Give it up" has two meanings that are different from "Give up" and "Give up on <something>":

- To wildly applaud.  (A master of ceremonies will often ask an audience to "Give it up for <the next person to appear>.")
- To willingly have sex with someone.  Using "give it up" with this meaning implies that the person who "gave it up" had sex earlier in the relationship than the speaker fully approves of, or in a less committed relationship than the speaker fully approves of.

Comment: I would say "at least two meanings"; there are likely more. But this kind of answer is really helpful in an ELL context.